# Distinct join between 2 tables

Tags: join, distinct, relation

[image]

this is my code : 
SELECT DISTINCT Emps.name, Degrees.Name AS degree, Degrees.Date AS degree_date

FROM            Emps INNER JOIN
Degrees ON Emps.id = Degrees.empId

but distict dosn't work , i want this result
[image]

i want distict name with degree which has max id or max date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all i found the solution

```
SELECT e.name, d.Name AS degree
FROM Emps AS e
full JOIN (
SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.empId ORDER BY t.id DESC) AS rn FROM Degrees AS t
) AS d ON e.id = d.empId
WHERE d.rn = 1
```